# can I get the document viewer Evince in Windows

Tags: evince

I want to get document viewer of Ubuntu working in Windows 7, is there any way to do it? If yes then please guide me through that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are referring to the Document Viewer Evince.
Yes, it is available for Windows:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads

Comment: archive.org has a mirror available for this download at Warwick university's website http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/download.opensuse.org/repositories/GNOME:/Apps:/Evince:/Windows:/3.6.1.0/openSUSE_12.2/noarch/mingw32-evince-msi-3.6.1-215.1.noarch.rpm . If any Windows users are having trouble with this download, use 7zip (or a similar file extracting program) to open the downloaded RPM file, and just click through each folder until you get to the msi file. Extract that out of the RPM file, and open it as you would any other installer.

Comment: @JackFifield Thank you for your information. That link brings a newer version 3.6.1.0. Unfortunately, in Windows 10, it crashes on start.

Comment: @VladimirS. FWIW, right now the link from this post refers to http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/ and although the link is kind of useless on its own *(you can't just unpack a package there and run binaries as they has dependencies)*, but you can install evince with mingw installer.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20170508115615/http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/evince/2.32/

Comment: @JackFifield The link in your comment is now out-of-date, leading to a 404. Luckily the Wayback Machine archived it: https://web.archive.org/web/20141226194123/http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/download.opensuse.org/repositories/GNOME:/Apps:/Evince:/Windows:/3.6.1.0/openSUSE_12.2/noarch/mingw32-evince-msi-3.6.1-215.1.noarch.rpm